# Error inserting row laravel 5.1 ORM mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have this code in laravel model:

```
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'We are gonna to save an order with shopify_id: '.$this->shopify_id]);
$this->save();
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'SQL of insert: ', 'sql' => DB::getQueryLog()]);
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'Order saved with shopify_id: '.$this->shopify_id]);
$orderInBD = Order::where('shopify_id', $this->shopify_id)->first();
Log::info($this->TAG.'.trySave ('.session()->getId().')', ['msg' => 'Order in BD with shopify_id: '.$orderInBD->shopify_id, 'order' => $orderInBD]);
```

And it show this in the log:

```
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"We are gonna to save an order with shopify_id: 5074805714"} 
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"SQL of insert: ","sql":[{"query":"insert into `orders` (`shopify_id`, `user_id`, `user_id_processed_temp`, `financial_status`, `paid_at`, `accepts_marketing`, `subtotal_local`, `subtotal_eur`, `shipping_local`, `shipping_eur`, `total_local`, `total_eur`, `billing_country`, `billing_street`, `billing_phone`, `billing_zip`, `billing_province`, `billing_city`, `billing_latitude`, `billing_longitude`, `shipping_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_province`, `shipping_province_code`, `shipping_phone`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_zip`, `shipping_latitude`, `shipping_longitude`, `name`, `cancelled_at`, `cancel_reason`, `created_at`, `created_at_day`, `gateway`, `source_name`, `draft`, `fulfillment_status`, `updated_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","bindings":[5074805714,null,1,"paid","2017-06-22T16:32:32+02:00",true,"44.00",44,"7.00",7,"51.00",51,"IT","Via n.34","334 616 6996","60041","AN","Sassoferrato",43.4292,12.8540,"IT","Via n.34","Ancona","AN","334 616 6996","","60041",43.4292,12.8540,"SITEMUERES1660269",null,null,"2017-06-22T16:32:32+02:00","2017-06-22T16:32:32+02:00","braintree","web",0,"fulfilled","2017-06-22T16:32:35+02:00"],"time":4.6}]} 
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"Order saved with shopify_id: 5074805714"} 
[2017-06-22 18:33:55] production.INFO: Order.trySave (sP9IZwqbzXLn4b6EF0pKZKrBRsyX1WEOx6M2XStM) {"msg":"Order in BD with Shopify_ID: 779838418","order":"[object] (App\\ModelosRelacionales\\Order: {\"id\":252,\"name\":\"SITEMUERES1660269\",\"created_at\":\"2017-06-22 16:32:32\",\"created_at_day\":\"2017-06-22\",\"paid_at\":\"2017-06-22 16:32:32\",\"financial_status\":\"paid\",\"accepts_marketing\":\"1\",\"discount_code\":null,\"cancelled_at\":null,\"cancel_reason\":null,\"refunded_at\":null,\"origen\":null,\"referal\":null,\"gateway\":\"braintree\",\"discount_category\":null,\"is_code_applied\":null,\"is_shipping_code_applied\":null,\"is_shipping_native_applied\":null,\"is_compare_at_price_applied\":null,\"subtotal_local\":\"44.00\",\"subtotal_eur\":\"44.00\",\"shipping_local\":\"7.00\",\"shipping_eur\":\"7.00\",\"total_local\":\"51.00\",\"total_eur\":\"51.00\",\"discount_amount_local\":null,\"discount_amount_eur\":null,\"code_discount_amount_local\":null,\"code_discount_amount_eur\":null,\"refunded_amount_local\":null,\"refunded_amount_eur\":null,\"shipping_discount_amount_local\":null,\"shipping_discount_amount_eur\":null,\"compare_at_discount_amount_local\":null,\"compare_at_discount_amount_eur\":null,\"total_real_discount_local\":null,\"total_real_discount_eur\":null,\"shipping_country\":\"IT\",\"shipping_province\":\"Ancona\",\"shipping_province_code\":\"AN\",\"shipping_phone\":\"334\",\"shipping_city\":\"a\",\"shipping_street\":\"a\",\"shipping_zip\":\"60041\",\"shipping_latitude\":\"43.429\",\"shipping_longitude\":\"12.854\",\"billing_province\":\"AN\",\"billing_zip\":\"6004\",\"billing_phone\":\"33\",\"billing_city\":\"\",\"billing_street\":\"Via n.34\",\"billing_country\":\"IT\",\"billing_latitude\":\"43.429\",\"billing_longitude\":\"12.854\",\"customer_id\":\"0\",\"shopify_id\":\"779838418\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-06-22 16:32:35\",\"fulfillment_status\":\"fulfilled\",\"source_name\":\"web\",\"draft\":\"0\",\"deleted_at\":null,\"user_id\":null,\"user_id_processed_temp\":\"1\"})"}
```

As you can see, the order returned a row with shopify_id different. In the insert i have 5074805714 and in the BD i have: 779838418

If i execute the query in phpmyadmin like this:

```
insert into `orders` (`shopify_id`, `user_id`, `user_id_processed_temp`, `financial_status`, `paid_at`, `accepts_marketing`, `subtotal_local`, `subtotal_eur`, `shipping_local`, `shipping_eur`, `total_local`, `total_eur`, `billing_country`, `billing_street`, `billing_phone`, `billing_zip`, `billing_province`, `billing_city`, `billing_latitude`, `billing_longitude`, `shipping_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_province`, `shipping_province_code`, `shipping_phone`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_zip`, `shipping_latitude`, `shipping_longitude`, `name`, `cancelled_at`, `cancel_reason`, `created_at`, `created_at_day`, `gateway`, `source_name`, `draft`, `fulfillment_status`, `updated_at`) values (5074805714, null, 1, "paid", "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", true, "24.00", 24, "7.00", 7, "31.00", 31, "es", "Calle", "766", "0311", "a", "busot", 38.4804, -0.4210, "ES", "calle", "a", "a", "6765", "busot", "03111", 38.4804688, -0.4210394, "SITEMUERES1660091", null, null, "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", "braintree", "web", 0, "fulfilled", "2017-06-22T16:09:37+02:00")
```

It works just fine.

The field structure shopify_id is bigint(20)

EDIT 1
If i do:

```
DB::insert('insert into `orders` (`shopify_id`, `user_id`, `user_id_processed_temp`, `financial_status`, `paid_at`, `accepts_marketing`, 
           `subtotal_local`, `subtotal_eur`, `shipping_local`, `shipping_eur`, `total_local`, `total_eur`, `billing_country`, 
           `billing_street`, `billing_phone`, `billing_zip`, `billing_province`, `billing_city`, `billing_latitude`, `billing_longitude`, 
           `shipping_country`, `shipping_street`, `shipping_province`, `shipping_province_code`, `shipping_phone`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_zip`, 
           `shipping_latitude`, `shipping_longitude`, `name`, `cancelled_at`, `cancel_reason`, `created_at`, `created_at_day`, `gateway`, `source_name`, 
           `draft`, `fulfillment_status`, `updated_at`) 
   values ('.$this->shopify_id.', null, 1, "paid", "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", true, "24.00", 24, "7.00", 7, "31.00", 31, "es", "Calle", "766", "0311", "a", "busot", 
           38.4804688, -0.4210394, "ES", "calle", "alicante", "a", "6765", "busot", "03111", 38.4804688, -0.4210394, "'.$this->name.'", null, null, "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", 
           "2017-06-22T16:09:31+02:00", "braintree", "web", 0, "fulfilled", "2017-06-22T16:09:37+02:00")');
```

It works fine.

EDIT 2
If i do:

```
$this->shopify_id -= 5000000000;
$this->save();
```

It works fine too. I know that Laravel can support big numbers because the same application in production is doing it fine.

EDIT 3

If i do:

```
$this->shopify_id = strval($json['id'])
```

It works

What can be happening?

Comment: Is `shopify_id` in the `$fillable` array in the model?

Comment: No, i dont have any field in the fillable array

Comment: Do you use multiple database connections?

Comment: Just one connection